# void type seems to overwrite the return type when used as an interface in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
interface Check {
name: string;
_meth(): void;
}

class ClassDemo implements Check {
name: string = 'something';
_meth() {
return 'string';
}
```

}

the interface clearly states that the type of the return for _meth should be of type void, but type script is not showing any error for the class implementation rather type inference is taking place, I know that void is a type for returning "void" ,i am new to typescript,an explanation for this would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a convenience thing, they're basically structurally compatible. I agree in the case of implementing an interface it doesn't make as much sense.

Consider a function that takes a Check interface:

```js
export function f(check: Check): void
{
    const s = check._meth();
    console.log(s.slice(0,1)); // compile error
}
```

If you can't access the return, it's like it doesn't exist :)

Comment: oh so it depends on the usage,if i return a value and the function  return is not assigned to anything ,its still void right,like that?

Comment: Whether or not you assign it the type will be void. The example I've given isn't a great one as console.log takes an any array, but the point stands.